# the better method to store page hits in crowded site

Tags: php

I have website with too much traffic, I want to add a hits counter. what the better method to store that ? ihave 2 options 
1- create DB and store hits in. 
2- create local txt file and store hits in. 
the server is already over loaded so what would be better to avoid more pressure on the server ?

Comment: The flat file may be a bit faster

Comment: When database management systems (DBMS) first were developed, they used multiple files per database, typically one file per table. Now days, most of the common DBMS systems use one file per database. A database is a type of file (or a group of files.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would **not** use a file.

If the server is already under high load it would get even worse if you add that additonal concurrent file (read/write) access

I'm confirm with @Antonys answer. It will delegate the work for stats to the clients and not to the server.

Comment: Thank you. i will go for that to see.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid further load on the server, use external services like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) and [Statcounter](http://statcounter.com).

Comment: Google Analytics does not give you exact hits, it uses some kind of approximations!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want use external services, best option is NoSQL database.

Comment: Thank you, is that a Sqlite ?

Answer (score 3):

Alternative PHP Cache (APC) would be an option.

Answer (score 2):

This is also another option for you 
https://www.kissmetrics.com/

Comment: Thank you , but i think i  can't add that code in a php- jpg file ? because i want to store hits from php page that work as a picture

Comment: you can add kissmetric event code using php as well as javascript . please refer this http://support.kissmetrics.com/apis/php.html